# How to append two NSData variable in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

I want to append two NSData:

```
    var actionIdData :NSData = NSData(bytes: &actionId, length: 2)
    var payLoad : NSData = NSData(bytes: &message, length: 9)

    var messageData : NSMutableData!

    messageData.appendData(actionIdData)
    messageData.appendData(actionIdData)
```

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to initialize your `messageData` before appending to it.

```
var messageData = NSMutableData() //or var messageData : NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
messageData.appendData(actionIdData)
messageData.appendData(payLoad)
```

Comment: i receive this error :  Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Comment: you need to initialize your messageData either like this `var messageData = NSMutableData()` or like `var messageData : NSMutableData = NSMutableData()` not both just one of them.

Comment: Have you try as i mention in above comment is it working now?

Answer (score 4):

Compatible with both **Swift 4** and **Swift 5** you can only use `append` function of `Data` to append two different data.

**Sample Usage**

```
guard var data1 = "data1".data(using: .utf8), let data2 = "data2".data(using: .utf8) else {
    return
}

data1.append(data2)
// data1 is now combination of data1 and data2
```

Answer (score 0):

### Convenient extension for Swift 5

```
extension Array where Element == Data {
   /**
    * Combines data
    * ## Examples:
    * [Data(),Data()].combined
    */
   var combined: Data {
      reduce(.init(), +)
   }
}
```

Comment: Still more convenient is `Data() + Data()` (without the extension).

Comment: @vadian Yes, but combined can do things like `Array(repeat: Data(), count: 100).combined` 