# How can I gzip a folder in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, gzip

I have a set of files of different types(i.e. .m4a, .mov, .csv) which are saved inside a folder named **Test**. Now, I want to gzip the folder & send it to server (in order to avoid multiple API calls).

I tried the following (Using **GzipSwift** Framework) :

```
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: getFolderUrl())
        let zippedData = try data.gzipped()
        try zippedData.write(to: destinationUrl)
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }

    func getFolderUrl() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        let dataPath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Test")
        return dataPath
    }
```

This gives the following error on first line:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “Test” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/Xx...xX/Documents/Test, NSUnderlyingError=0x283151500 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied"}}

Comment: Maybe Data(contentsOf:) doesn’t work with an url pointing to a folder, perhaps try with a file in that folder and see if it works?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, It works with url pointing to file but I want to gzip the folder & send gzipped folder to server.

Comment: Well at least you know what caused the issue now. It looks like you can merge data objects so that is one possible route, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39304944/how-to-append-two-nsdata-variable-in-swift for instance.